# How to install terminal application globally?

Tags: macos, terminal, macports

So I mess around with terminal once in a while. Occasionally I find I have to compile from source with the usual:

```
./configure
make
(sudo) make install
```

I'm trying to install gtk+ following the instructions on the build page of:
https://wiki.gnome.org

it suggests using a different account for those who have macports or fink installed. So thats what I'm doing.

I realized this means some stuff won't be available, but I'm literally scouring the internet for obscure packages that apparently I don't have, because I can't get past step one: install a bunch of supporting modules. I have XCode installed.

Why isn't at least some of the stuff I installed in my main account showing up for all users? I thought source installation did this by default? like in /usr/bin or /usr/lib?

I don't want to mess with my path too much as the whole point was to have a clean path free of macports/fink influence (I had both).

IDK what the issue with macports/fink is exactly, but is it possible to link against main libraries without linking macports/fink?

EDIT: Is it possible to make some ports selectively available for all users but not all?
I don't fully understand what exactly about macports (maybe just some of the ported utilities) doesn't work with gtk+ and jhbuild. But maybe thats a start

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Do you need help in installing the bunch of supporting modules (then please add details about the errors you are receiving)? Or are you wondering where the stuff installed via your main account ended up in? Or something else?

Comment: why not install gtk+ using macports it makes it easier. Only compile using configure et al when it is not in the port, also macports and fink are installed for all users.

Comment: tried macports: It wanted me to install cairo with quartz through macports which it would never find. I couldn't find a way around it

Comment: Voted to reopen — I think I understand what you mean and have a potential answer

Comment: @grgarside can you edit your understanding of the question into the text before we reopen it? This will give the OP a chance to confirm your understanding and everybody else a chance to follow the answer.

Comment: @patrix I'm not certain and I'd end up re-writing the question, so in case I'm wrong I'll comment first: OP has installed MacPorts and various ports, but wants *some* of the installed CLIs to be available to *all* users on the Mac. OP doesn't want to edit the path for all users since that would add all ports to all users.

Comment: That sounds close enough to what my issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new folder somewhere accessible by all users.
2. Symlink a number of executables into that folder so that only the executables that you want to be accessible in all user accounts are in that folder.

   ```
   ln -s /opt/local/yourport /path/to/your/folder/yourport
   ```
3. Add the path to your new folder to the top of `/etc/paths`. Since this file is read by all user accounts, it is added to the path for all users. However, since you're adding the new folder, you're not adding all the ports to everyone's path.

Comment: This was really straightforward and easy. Thank you. I submitted a comment before this saying I was gonna try something else, but I tried this and worked like a charm. I also noticed I earned the "quitter" badge. Any idea how I can get rid of that?

Comment: I was joking around. Sorry

Comment: @jasondanks Haha :)